# IProgress doesnt' report

Tags: vb.net, async-await, progress-bar

I have the following code to report a progress. The function `CalculateMandelbrot()` seems to work asynchronous, but my progress bar shows nothing.

```
Public Class Form1
    Private Async Function Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) As Task Handles Button1.Click
        Dim prog As Progress(Of Integer) = New Progress(Of Integer)(Function(x) ProgressBar1.Value = x)
        Await Task.Run(Function() CalculateMandelbrot(prog))
        Dim ende As Boolean = True
    End Function

    Private Function CalculateMandelbrot(ByVal progress As IProgress(Of Integer))
        For xi = 0 To 100
            Threading.Thread.Sleep(40)
            progress.Report(xi)
        Next
        Return 42
    End Function
End Class
```

Comment: Never use `Thread.Sleep`. Use `await Task.Delay` and make the method `Async`.

Comment: @Aluan Haddad: I used the example of Stephen Cleary. His worker function is not async. Also I deleted the Tread.Sleep and increased my counter variable to 1000000. But still no progress is reported.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
   Dim prog = New Progress(Of Integer)(Function(x) ProgressBar1.Value = x)
```

The compiler struggles mightily to make sense of this code.  Note that the lambda expression is a Function and a function needs to have a return value.  Where does it come from?  What is the return value type of the lambda expression?

Hopefully you see the trap.  The only thing it can do is assume you meant to return a Boolean.  So you get a comparison between the values of Value and x.  In other words, it is compiled as `Return (ProgressBar1.Value = x)`.  A Boolean, that return value is not actually getting used.

Not an assignment, thus no progress bar update.  Write it correctly to fix the bug:

```
   Dim prog = New Progress(Of Integer)(Sub(x) ProgressBar1.Value = x)
```